# Show that $\sqrt{2\pi n}\Pr(S_n=k)\to\exp(-x^2/2)$

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-distribution, central-limit-theorem

> If $\Pr(S_n=k)=e^{-n}\frac{n^k}{k!}$ then as $\frac{(k-n)}{\sqrt n}\to x$, show that $\sqrt{2\pi n}\Pr(S_n=k)\to\exp(-x^2/2)$

$e^{-n}\frac{n^k}{k!}=e^{-n}\frac{n^n}{n!}\times n^{k-n}\frac{n!}{k!}\tag1$

according to Stirling's Formula, the first term tends to $\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$

so the second must be equal to $\exp(-x^2/2)$

Using Stirling again;

$n^{k-n}\frac{n!}{k!}=\dfrac{n^n/e^n\sqrt{2\pi n}}{k^k/e^k\sqrt{2\pi k}}=\sqrt{n/k}\ e^{k-n}(\frac nk)^k$

$(\star)$ and $(\frac nk)^k=\frac{n}{x\sqrt n +n}^{x\sqrt n +n}=(1-\frac{x\sqrt n}{x\sqrt n +n})^{x\sqrt n +n}\to e^{-x\sqrt n}=e^{-(k-n)}$

and it gives finally $\sqrt{n/k}*e^{k-n}(\frac nk)^k=\sqrt{n/k}*e^{k-n}e^{-(k-n)}=\sqrt{\frac nk}$

so what did go wrong, maybe $(\star)$ is not correct ?

I think, I cannot just separate the product in $(1)$ and assume that the first term converges to $\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$ as n goes to $\infty$, since if $n\to\infty$ the whole formula doesn't make sense, but can you suggest another way ?

Comment: It might help to note that $k$ must be a function of $n$ in this context. Thus in the exponent $k-n=\sqrt{n}x+o(\sqrt{n})$ and in the denominator $k=n+\sqrt{n}x+o(\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: In other words you are looking at $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{\sqrt{n}x+o(\sqrt{n})} \frac{n!}{(n+\sqrt{n}x+o(\sqrt{n}))!}$.

Comment: You can't say that $e^{-n}\frac{n^n}{n!}$ "tends to" $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$, but rather that $e^{-n}\frac{n^n}{n!}\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$. Also, when you use Stirling after that, you write $=$ instead of $\sim$. This may be a reason why you're confused. Keep in mind that $n$ tends to $\infty$ and that $k$ depends on $n$ in such a way that $\frac{k-n}{\sqrt{n}}$ tends has a limit, that we call $x$.

Comment: Eh, I don't think that first part was a significant problem: since $e^n \frac{n^n}{n!}$ is asymptotic to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi n}}$, $\sqrt{2 \pi n}$ times that actually *tends* to $1$. That reduces the problem to considering the second factor.

Comment: By the way, this also follows more or less immediately from the CLT if you realize that $e^{-n} \frac{n^k}{k!}$ is the PMF of a sum of $n$ independent Poisson(1) variables, each of which has mean $1$ and variance $1$. For then $\frac{S_n-n}{\sqrt{n}}$ is asymptotically N(0,1), so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were slightly sloppy earlier: Stirling says that $\sqrt{2 \pi n} e^n \frac{n^n}{n!}$ (with the leading factor) tends to $1$. Without that leading factor you can't really say "tends to", you should say "is asymptotic to", since the actual limit would be zero.

As for the rest of the problem, you should first notice that $k$ must be a function of $n$ for your limit to make sense. With that in mind, first notice that the case $x=0$ is basically just Stirling's approximation. (A *little* bit of extra work is needed since $k$ needn't be exactly $n$ in this situation, but it's not a big deal.)

So now assume $x>0$ and thus $k \geq n$. (The latter is no real requirement, since it must be true eventually if $x> 0$.) The argument is similar when $x<0$.

After you cancel out the top factorial with part of the bottom factorial, you are left with a product of $k-n$ terms divided by a product of $k-n$ terms. Specifically:

$$\frac{n^{k-n}}{\prod_{i=1}^{k-n} (n+i)}.$$

Cancelling factors of $n$ gives

$$\frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^{k-n} (1+i/n)}.$$

Take the log of this and see what you can do. (It's a nice exercise.)

Comment: Yes I think I got it,  taking log of the denominator gives $\sum_1^{k-n}i/n=(k-n)(k-n-1)/2n\approx (k-n)^2/2n$ then exponentiating gives the result

Comment: @ketum You need to be a bit careful with the Taylor expansion of the log: the fact that $k-n$ is much smaller than $n$ is essential here.

Comment: Yeah of course $\log(1+x)$ is almost equal to $x$ only for small $x$, thanks

Comment: Why is $k$ a function of $n$? I thought $k$ was supposed to be a constant in this case?

Comment: @RicardoCorralesBarquero They want to send $n\to \infty$ in such a way that $(k-n)/\sqrt{n} \to x$ where $x$ is finite and nonzero. If $k$ is constant then this cannot happen.