# Does $\sqrt{2\pi n} P(S_n =k)\to \exp(-x^2/2)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

This is exercise 3.1.2 from the 4th edition of Prof. Durrett's probability:

> Suppose $X_i$ have a Poisson distribution with mean $1$, $S_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$, and $(k-n)/\sqrt{n}\to x$, then prove $$\sqrt{2\pi n} P(S_n =k)\to \exp(-x^2/2)\,.$$

Here's my attempt:

\begin{align}
\sqrt{2\pi n} P(S_n =k)&=\sqrt{2\pi n} e^{-n}n^{k}/k!
\\&\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}e^{-n}n^{k}/ \sqrt{2\pi k}e^{-k}k^{k}
\\&=e^{k-n}(n/k)^{1/2+k}
\\&=e^{k-n}(1+(k-n)/n)^{-1/2-k}
\\&\to e^{k-n}(1+x/\sqrt{n})^{-1/2-k}\to e^{-x^2}
\end{align}

My last step is problematic. How should I continue from the second to last step?

Comment: Could you show the calculation that obtains $e^{-x^2}$?

Comment: I made a mistake there, thanks!

Comment: I found another post related to this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3716392/does-sqrt2-pi-n-ps-n-k-to-exp-x2-2. Combined with exercise 3.1.1 of 4th edition of prof Durrett's book I got $e^{-x^2/2}$. Thanks

Comment: You seem to have linked back to this.

Comment: sorry, the link is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1659857/show-that-sqrt2-pi-n-prs-n-k-to-exp-x2-2

Answer (score 1):

Instead write $(n/k)^{1/2+k}=(1+(n-k)/k)^{1/2+k}=(1-x\sqrt{n}/k)^{1/2+k}$. The Stirling-approximated log-probability is$$\begin{align}k-n+(1/2+k)\ln(1-x\sqrt{n}/k)&=x\sqrt{n}+(1/2+k)\ln(1-x\sqrt{n}/k)\\&=x\sqrt{n}+(1/2+k)(-x\sqrt{n}/k-x^2n/(2k^2)+o(x^2))\\&=-x\sqrt{n}/(2k)-x^2n/(2k)-x^2n/(4k^2).\end{align}$$With $k\approx n$, the $x$ coefficient $\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, while the $x^2$ coefficient $\to-1/2$.

Comment: I don't think you could replace $k-n$ with $x\sqrt{n}$ though.

Comment: Ah, I've run into this problem. We are given $\dfrac{k-n}{\sqrt{n}} \to x$. Does that imply $k-n \to x\sqrt{n}?$ Is that type of manipulation allowed? Is that why you "replaced" $k-n$ with $ x \sqrt{n}$? I posted a question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4286609/question-involving-limits