# Limit question: Does $(k-n)/\sqrt{n} \to x$ imply $k-n \to x\sqrt{n}?$

Tags: calculus, probability-limit-theorems

Let $k$ be some constant. If $$\dfrac{k-n}{\sqrt{n}} \to x \;\;\text{as} \;\;n \to \infty$$ does it follow that $$k-n \to x \sqrt{n} \;\;\text{as} \;\; n \to \infty?$$
I looked at Calculus limit laws, but I'm not finding any insight of whether this type of manipulation is allowed or not. Any feedback would be appreciated!  For context, this is from a question from Durrett's Probability Text, Problem 3.1.2. Here's a snippet of the problem: "Use Stirling's formula to show that if $(k-n)/\sqrt{n} \to x$, then $\sqrt{2\pi n}P(S_n =k) \to exp(-x^2/2)$ where $P(S_n=k)=e^{-n}n^k/k!$"

EDIT:
I am asking this question because I see the $x\sqrt{n}$ being used in the solution and am having a hard time justifying Durrett's usage of it.

[image]

Comment: What is the meaning of your second line? $x\sqrt{n}$ tends to infinity as $n\to \infty$, what is the meaning of $k-n$ converging to it?

Comment: Right. I see what you mean. I'm confused myself. I edited my post for clarity and more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
&\sqrt {2\pi n} P(S_n  = k)  = \sqrt {2\pi n} e^{ - n} \frac{{n^k }}{{k!}} \sim e^{k - n} \left( {\frac{n}{k}} \right)^{k + 1/2}  = e^{k - n} \left( {1 + \frac{{n - k}}{k}} \right)^{k + 1/2} 
\\ &
 = \exp \left[ {k - n + \left( {k + \frac{1}{2}} \right)\log \left( {1 + \frac{{n - k}}{k}} \right)} \right]
\\ &
 = \exp \left[ {k - n + \left( {k + \frac{1}{2}} \right)\left( {\frac{{n - k}}{k} - \frac{{(n - k)^2 }}{{2k^2 }} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{{(n - k)^3 }}{{k^3 }}} \right)} \right)} \right]
\\ &
 = \exp \left[ { - \frac{{(n - k)^2 }}{{2k}} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{{(n - k)^3 }}{{k^2 }}} \right) + \frac{{n - k}}{{2k}} - \frac{{(n - k)^2 }}{{4k^2 }} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{{(n - k)^3 }}{{k^3 }}} \right)} \right].
\end{align*}
By assumption, $k - n = x\sqrt n  + o(\sqrt n )$, giving
$$
\sqrt {2\pi n} P(S_n  = k) = \exp \left[ { - \frac{{x^2 n}}{{2k}} + o\!\left( {\frac{n}{k}} \right) + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\sqrt n }}} \right)} \right].
$$
Again by assumption, $k = n + \mathcal{O}(\sqrt n )$, giving
$$
\sqrt {2\pi n} P(S_n  = k) = \exp \left[ { - \frac{{x^2 }}{2} + o(1)} \right].
$$

Comment: wow, so sophisticated! :) can you explain why $k-n=x\sqrt{n} + o(\sqrt{n})$? I took calculus and am now learning some probability theory. I have not seen this type of thinking before. I appreciate the time you took to write this argument.

Comment: $$
\frac{{k - n}}{{\sqrt n }} \to x \Leftrightarrow \frac{{k - n}}{{\sqrt n }} = x + o(1) \Leftrightarrow k - n = x\sqrt n  + o(\sqrt n )
$$

Comment: Nice! Thank you!